# How to prove a function is harmonic polynomial

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C93kl.png)! How to prove this function a harmonic polynomial using Laplace equation

[image]For the 1 question I know we can prove harmonic using Laplace Equation but for this on m confused how to start.
For the 2 one I tried definition of closed and open set. I think that f is a function from closed set to a closed disk so f(K) is closed in S when K is closed in [0,2]. Am i right or not?